# javascript convert file into byte array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a `file.mp3` file right now. I need to convert it into a format of byte array. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Question extension:
The file is not limited to `.mp3` format?

In addition to byte array, I have some other options as well, e.g.

1. an Object like `{ base64: "..." }` with a `base64-encoded` String
2. a Buffer in Node.js runtime.
3. a Stream in Node.js runtime.

Comment: Use the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

Answer (score 0):

If doing from a User's upload:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* external.js */
var doc, bod, I, old = onload;
onload = function(){
if(old)old(); // change old var name if using technique on other pages
doc = document; bod = doc.body;
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
function readAsBytes(file, done, doneContext){
  var fr = new FileReader, c = doneContext || this;
  fr.onload = function(){
    done.call(c, fr.result.replace(/^data.+,/, ''));
  }
  fr.readAsDataURL(file);
}
var frm = I('frm'), out = I('out');
frm.onsubmit = function(){
  // stuff you need to happen - use AJAX
  return false;
}
I('up').onchange = function(){
  readAsBytes(this.files[0], function(res){
    // ArrayInstance assignment to .innerHTML automatically does ArrayInstance.join(',')
    out.innerHTML = res.split(''); // don't use split, if you don't want an Array
  });
}
}
//]]>
```

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
body{
  background:#000; overflow-y:scroll;
}
.main{
  width:936px; background:#fff; padding:20px; margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />
    <title>readAsBytes()</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <form id='frm' name='frm'>
      <input id='up' name='up' type='file' />
    </form>
    <div id='out'></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works for the case of user uploading file. But in my case, it is on the cellphone.
I build an app with Ionic3 framework. I need to do an audio recording, so I created an audio file of type "MediaObject", then I need to transfer this "MediaObject" into one of the above forms I listed. So there won't be a file uploading input like in the browser.

Comment: Thanks, I just solved the problem two minutes ago. I transform it first into binary string, and then I use base64 to encode it, finally I can successfully send the audio. It cost me two whole days.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem. Instead of byte array, I go with another option, the base64 encode string. 
So first, I use an Ionic plugin to transform it into binary string (I think javascript already has an API FileReader.readAsBinaryString() which can do the same thing ); second I simply use btoa() to transform the binary string into base64 encode string.

Answer (score -1):

Check here:

[Local file access with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)

The straight answer is that JavaScript itself doesn't contain file access, but when you program in JavaScript, you aren't programming in JUST JavaScript, but also against some back-end.  (Perhaps Chrome, perhaps IE, perhaps Node.JS)

The file access is not part of JavaScript, but of the back-end, and how it works will vary from one environment to the next.

If the other question I mentioned doesn't have your answer, you'll need to write back with what browser or other framework you're running JavaScript in.

Comment: Hi, I'm working with Ionic3 framework to build a mobile app. Ionic3 is based on angularJS and javascript. 
So in my situation, I need to do audio recording. So I created an audio file which is  "MediaObject" type, then I need to transfer this "MediaObject" into one of the forms I listed above.